# Tables from 1-20 having rows with alternating color scheme

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print tables of 1-20 and put an alternating color scheme of red and green(odd rows have green and even rows have red) in the rows using Javascript. I have also put a checkbox at the start of each row for later use but somehow the color scheme isn't working.

```
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <script>
            for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
            {

                if((i%2)==0)
                {
                    document.getElementById('r'+i).style.background="red";
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('r'+i).style.background="green";
                }
                document.write("<tr id='r"+i+"'>");
                document.write("<td><input type='checkbox' id='c_box'></td>");
                for(j=1; j<=20; j++)
                {
                    document.write("<td>"+i*j+"</td>");
                }
                document.write("</tr>");
            }
        </script>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: The element doesn't exist yet when setting the style.

Comment: you could also achieve this with CSS using the `nth-child()` selector which makes it much easier. As @Caramiriel points out the element doesn't exists yet when you apply the styling. Still, you are better of using CSS for this

Comment: Why are you doing this with JavaScript? It's a CSS responsibility. `tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: green; }` and `tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: red; }`. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: But I want to accomplish the task using javascript. What is the way out for that?

Comment: @TimothySmith put if condition after `document.write`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change color by css, so may be what you are trying to do is not the right way. 
However, the actual problem in your code is you are trying to set color before you write the elements. Folllowing code will solve your issue

```
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <script>
                for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
                {
                    document.write("<tr id='r"+i+"'>");
                    document.write("<td><input type='checkbox' id='c_box'></td>");
                    for(j=1; j<=20; j++)
                    {
                        document.write("<td>"+i*j+"</td>");
                    }
                    document.write("</tr>");


                    if((i%2)==0)
                    {
                        document.getElementById('r'+i).style.background="red";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById('r'+i).style.background="green";
                    }
                }
        </script>
    </table>
</body>
```

The thing is you need to add a control before you change the color. `document.getElementById('r'+i)` is trying to find the control but the control does not exists, thus it gets an error. If you F12 and go to console tab you will see an erre something like

> Cannot read property 'style' of null

The order is very important

Comment: Thanks @MJK, the code works like a charm. I could't upvote you because I dont have enough reputation points but I have marked your answer.

Comment: @TimothySmith Glad to help you, thanks for accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using css, see the example below. 
Append your table to dom and keep this css.

```
tr:nth-child(even){
  background: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```css
tr:nth-child(even){
  background: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Using Javascript

var tr = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
for(var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){
if(i%2 == 0){
tr[i].style.backgroundColor = '#E74C3C';
}else if(i%2 ==1){
tr[i].style.backgroundColor = "#229954";
}
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```